# Facebook graph api can't get user public profile

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I've implemented social authentication in my application, and I get the accesstoken successfully.
But when I use that access token to get the user's public profile, I get only the user's ID and the user's name. 
I can't get the other properties of the user like the user's profile picture.

when I try this:

```
Json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync($"https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/{userWithOnlyId.Id}?access_token={accessToken}");
```

I get only the user's id and name.

when I do this as stated in [this facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile/) :

```
await httpClient.GetStringAsync(
            $"https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=profile_pic&access_token={accessToken}");
```

I get a  403 forbidden error.

Is there something I did wrong ? I've tried several things I found here on stackoverflow but up till now I have no solution.

Comment: The documentation you linked to is for getting a user’s basic information, when they are messaging your Facebook bot / page. Are we even talking about that scenario here? When you say you implemented social authentication in your app, then I would assume we are talking normal Graph API user profile, not messenger. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Answer (score 0):

There is an example(section: Retrieving a Person's Profile):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<PSID>?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Looks like you need to provide a PSID

*ASID(App-scoped ID) - it's a user-id that is unique for each app.*

It means that this user will have different ASID for each app. I think that you have only one app.

> To get a Page-scoped ID from an App-scoped ID, send a POST request to
>   the /pages_id_mapping root node
>   [image]

Comment: HI, thanks for your reply. by psid you mean user id ?

Comment: @JohnCode
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/psid-api

Comment: Sorry if my question is kind of silly, but I read the doc you sent and didn't find where to get the PSID from, can you please tell me where I can get it from ?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying that now

Comment: I've been trying the above method, but it seems to be working for facebook pages only. Cause, I get this error response : " This method must be called with a Page Access Token"

Comment: I query the API in C# here is how I do it:   ```
            var hashed = FacebookHelper.GenerateFacebookSecretProof(token, _facebookAppSecret);
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                user_ids = id,
                appsecret_proof = hashed,
                access_token = token
            });

            var res = await (await httpClient.PostAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/pages_id_mapping", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens You need to use page access token

Comment: When I'm using your method of getting PSID from ASID (by `pages_id_mapping`) I receive `(#200) This app or page is not allowed to use this API.`. Any thoughts?